# How to write test cases for ExecutorServices?

Tags: java, mockito, executorservice, powermockito, testcase

I have a method which is using ExecutorService to create and execute multiple threads. Code works fine. Now I want to write JUNIT test case for the same. 
Code is as below :

```
private void method(Long input1, object result)
{
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    List<Callable< myObject>> callables = Arrays.asList(    callables as List);
    try 
    {
        List<Future< myObject>> futures = executor.invokeAll(callables);
        executor.shutdown();
        for(Future< myObject> f : futures)
        {
            method(f, result);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am new to JUnit test cases. I have looked for answers on internet but there are no specific answers to my problem.

I need a help to write test case so that it comes under Jacoco coverage. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "there are no specific answers to my problem", so far, you haven't mentioned a specific problem.

Comment: You need to refactor this code to be able to test it. In principle you should not aim for  "pure" line coverage but aim for testing the purpose of the method.

Comment: @Stultuske I dont know how to start. How to mock Executors ans ExecutorService. and then how to mock executor.invokeAll method so that it return List of Futures.

Comment: @HakanDilek Apart from 'for' loop, I dont see anything that can be refactored.

Comment: @Pratiksoni ExecutorService is a local variable, that you can't mock. first refactoring: make the service not a local one

Answer (score 0):

With the help of `PowerMockito` you can mock the static method:
`Executors.newFixedThreadPool`.

```java
ExecutorService executors = Mockito.mock(ExecutorService.class);
Mockito.when(executors.invokeAll()).thenReturn( <list of futures> );

PowerMockito.mockStatic(Executors.class);
PowerMockito.when(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(anyInt())).thenReturn(executors);
```

Aim to use a real `list` containing real `Future`'s (if possible).

*(Also do not forget to put the correct classes into the `@PrepareForTest` Annotation)*

---

Whether such a test makes sense depends on what `method(f, result);` is doing. If we assume its a `private` method, there is probably no other way of testing/covering it.

---

Also its probably not a good idea to have the submission of tasks to an `ExecutorService` and the handling of the results in a **blocking** method, so consider a refactoring anyway.